# DirectorySearcher contains filter on two properties

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to search users in active directory and apply 'contains' filter on two concatenated properties. So it should be something like:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(property1 + " " + property2=*keyword*))
```

Is it possible to achieve this with DirectorySearcher?

Comment: What not search that property1 contains keyword OR property2 contains keyword?

Comment: That will not work, e.g. if property1 is "abc", property 2 is "def", and the keyword is "abc d".

Comment: Deleted my answer. Now I got it.

Comment: You are talking about the `filter` property of `DirectorySearcher`. Dont know if concatenating is possible.

Comment: I also couldn't find a way how to achieve it, but I don't have much experience with AD, so thought that someone else could know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do any concatenations in LDAP filters.

But you could split it up and check if *either* property contains a keyword:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(|(property1=*keyword*)(property2=*keyword*)))
```

Note that any searches that use a wildcard at the beginning can make the search perform very slowly since no indexes can be used to do that matching.

The documentation on how to construct LDAP queries is [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx).

Comment: Will it be slower than retrieving all users and compare locally?